# Error occurs while installing the NUGET package in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm trying to install Nokia Imaging  SDK via NUGET under Visual Studio 2013 at my Windows Phone 8  project but every time I'm getting the following error:

> A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(TargetPlatformVersion)" that
>   evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition
>   "'$(TargetPlatformVersion)' > '8.0'".  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Answer (score 100, accepted):

When I got this error I just restarted Visual Studio and the error went away.

Please note, when I did restart the project did initially load, but I just right clicked and hit reload target and it did.

Comment: Note that I arrived here assuming that Resharper may need to be re-installed (8.2) but this was not necessary thanks to this simple solution. It is possible however that Resharper may have been responsible for the corruption so I disabled it during the visual studio restart just to be sure. It all works now thanks!

Comment: @TheSenator probably you read https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3996 too, I was just about to un-install resharper too :D

Comment: @Ali Amiri yes I read exactly that article! Also, I'm never satisfied with a 'reinstall and everything will be OK' mantra as it rarely is that simple and usually just wastes time! Glad you succeeded :)

Comment: Getting this error on project creation (Add new project) with resharper disabled.

Comment: @nVentimiglia, update NuGet Package Manager to latest, and also ReSharper if you don't want to uninstall it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have ReSharper installed it sounds like it could be this [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-408376).  This effected version 8.2 and has been fixed in build version 8.2.0.3169 and onwards.